# Is it able to get the staked amount on the specific pool on bnb chain by wallet address?

Tags: google-sheets, smartcontracts, cryptocurrency

I would like to get the info by interacting with this function to get staked amount
https://bscscan.com/address/0xc31c1027cedd0fabfc9d6118ff6423cf39f04523#readContract#F17

is it able to do this on google sheet?
If it is not, how can i do this?

- I would like to get the staked amount for the specific pool
- Get the info from the token contract on the BNB chain
- I would like to use it for getting around 200 wallet addresses info